# How can I loop django model fields in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model called 'Column' that has a relationship with my 'Type' model. I want to loop the 'Column' model by 30 in the form. Instead of showing 2 fields in the form, I want to show 30 fields in the column form. How can I do this?

```
class Type(models.Model):

    TYPE_OF_DATA = (

        ('Number', 'Number'),

        ('character', 'character'),

        ('check_box', 'check_box'),

        ('date', 'date'),

        ('image', 'image'),

             )

    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices= TYPE_OF_DATA)

class Column(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     selec_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.forms.py:

from django import forms
from .models import Column

class ColumnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ['name', 'selec_type']

app.views.py:

From .forms import ColumnForm
From django.forms import formset_factory

def design(request):
    ColumnFormSet = formset_factory=(ColumnForm, extra=30)
    formset = ColumnFormSet
    return render (request, 'design.html', {'formset':formset})
```

```
Template.design.html:

<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form}}
   {% for form in formset %}
        {{Form.as_p}}
   {% endfor %}
<button type='submit'>Save<button/>
<form/>
```

[Django Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/)